# polyglossia undoes font changes from ClassicThesis

Tags: fonts, fontspec, classicthesis

I'm trying to use the `classicthesis.sty` style class together with `polyglossia` with the result that `polyglossia` reverts all the changes to the fonts made by (I assume) `classicthesis.sty` (palatino for the normal font and such ...). While trying to fix the problem I'm completely stuck: I do not even see how and where `classicthesis.sty` sets the fonts --  the source is [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/?lang=en).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `Classicthesis` loads by default `mathpazo` which is built on `Palatino`. You might try to load `newpx` which relies on `TeXGyrePagella`, a Palatino clone, and  add to your preamble `\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagella}`.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal (non) working example?

Comment: I think I just found the bug: `polyglossia` implicitly loads `fontspec` and that package overrides the fonts loaded via `\RequirePackage{mathpazo}`.

Comment: @jules did you find a solution or workaround for this bug?

Comment: Check this answer for possible hints http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351100/68905