# Smallcaps with TeX Gyre Pagella and XeLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia, small-caps

This question is already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/how-can-i-produce-tex-gyre-pagella-smallcaps-using-xelatex), but accepted answer reverts to pdflatex, which won't work for this project.

I originally specified Palatino font with `\usepackage[sc, osf]{mathpazo}`, however I have [learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300655/polyglossia-undoes-font-changes-from-classicthesis) that since `polyglossia`, which I need for various international languages, implicitly loads `fontspec`, I am instead using `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}`, a font which I manually installed on the (OS X) system from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org) download.

`TeX Gyre Pagella` doesn't seem to include smallcaps, so I downloaded and installed `Palatino Small Caps & Old Style Figures.ttf` as shown here:

```
fc-list | grep Palatino
/Users/mikekilmer/Library/Fonts/Palatino Small Caps & Old Style Figures.ttf: Palatino Small Caps & Old Style,Palatino:style=Regular,Small Caps & Old Style Figures
/System/Library/Fonts/Palatino.ttc: Palatino:style=Bold
/System/Library/Fonts/Palatino.ttc: Palatino:style=Regular
/System/Library/Fonts/Palatino.ttc: Palatino:style=Bold Italic
/System/Library/Fonts/Palatino.ttc: Palatino:style=Italic
```

As far as I can tell from the following font info, Palatino-SC would be the name to reference to use:

```
otfinfo -i '~/Library/Fonts/Palatino Small Caps & Old Style Figures.ttf'
Family:              Palatino Small Caps & Old Style
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Palatino-SC
PostScript name:     Palatino-SC
Version:             001.001
Unique ID:           Palatino Small Caps & Old Style Figures:1178633258
Copyright:           Copyright (c) 1985, 1987, 1989, 1990, 1991 Adobe Systems Incorporated.  All Rights Reserved.Palatino is a trademark of Linotype AG and/or its subsidiaries.
```

But in this example, there's no small caps displayed:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,11pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,
SmallCapsFont={Palatino-SC},
SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
 ]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Once upon a time} we had a story. Once upon a time.
\end{document}
```

What IS working, is the following `fontspec` font family substitution:

```
\newfontfamily\scshape[Letters=SmallCaps,Scale=1.15]{Palatino-SC}
```

Can someone explain 1. Why the `setmainfont` parameters aren't working and 2. How I can get OldStyleNums to display?

Comment: Did you load `fontspec`?

Comment: @Bernard `polyglossia` does it

Comment: Why should you need to substitute the font? With `\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}` I get small caps.

Comment: i have spent at least a couple of hours (from a fairly ignorant place) troubleshooting this.

Comment: @egreg: Didn't know that! Thank you for the information.

Comment: Not sure why, but I'm not getting small caps. Are you getting them simply with `\textsc`?

Comment: @egreg what output do you get for `fc-list | grep Pagella`?

Comment: @MikeiLL What's the point of using `fc-list` on Mac OS X?

Comment: @egreg you mean because Font Book would display the info? It's just what I found to list source files and styles.

Comment: @MikeiLL I decided long ago to copy the fonts from the TeX Live directories in `/Library/Fonts` and so make things simpler when calling them. Anyway, `otfinfo -v` on `texgyrepagella-regular.otf` says `Version 2.004;PS 2.004;hotconv 1.0.49;makeotf.lib2.0.14853
` and with `otfinfo -f` I see the `smcp` feature listed.

Comment: @egreg is `smcp` the smallcaps feature? I also see `Small Capitals` listed for `smcp`.

Comment: Do you know how I can confirm that that is actually the font that `TeX Gyre Pagella` is referencing?

Comment: @MikeiLL Feature names are four letter long; they also have a “long name”; so `smcp` stands for Small Capitals. In my experiment, I have no problem at all in obtaining them with TeX Gyre Pagella. In order to see what font is used with XeLaTeX, you call it from the command line with `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" filename.tex`, so you get verbose output on the terminal that also lists the used font files.

Comment: Do you mean CTAN rather than CPAN? There is a CPAN, but it seems an unlikely choice here. As far as I know, `fc-list` will not necessarily tell you which fonts are available or will be used by XeTeX/LuaTeX on OS X, because `fontconfig` is not the native font-handling system. On Linux, it would tell you, but on OS X, you end up with distinct font management software and you need to know which one is being used for what. (This is true on Linux, too, but much less so as almost everything now uses `fontconfig`.) At least, this is how it worked when I used OS X, which isn't recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining fonts within XeLaTeX depends on how you installed them.

If TeX Gyre Pagella is available as a system font, then

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Numbers=OldStyle,
]

\begin{document}

\textsc{Once upon a time} we had a story. Once upon a time.

1234567890

\end{document}
```

will suffice. Otherwise, you need to use the fonts in the TeX Live distribution with a slightly more complicated method.

If I run the example with `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"`, I get the following output on the terminal:

```
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2017.01.29:2158
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf".
(CID:TeXGyrePagella-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
></Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf@9.96pt>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf"...
(CID:/Library/Fonts/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf[SMRJXI+TeXGyrePagella-Regular][CIDFontType0][39 glyphs][5175 bytes])
```

which shows I installed the TeX Gyre fonts in `/Library/Fonts` and these are used by `xdvipdfmx`.

The slightly more complicated version is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{texgyrepagella}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
]

\begin{document}

\textsc{Once upon a time} we had a story. Once upon a time.

1234567890

\end{document}
```

and the verbose output becomes

```
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2017.01.29:2202
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf".
(CID:TeXGyrePagella-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
></usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf@9.96pt>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf"...
(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf[KRFMAA+TeXGyrePagella-Regular][CIDFontType0][39 glyphs][5175 bytes])
```

showing that TeX Live directories are used.

The output is the same in both cases.

[image]

As you see, small caps are honored.

Comment: The culprit turns out to have been `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` which I had added at some point to show text figures, and as a set of "Palatino-like fonts" I guess was overriding the other fonts (though it was previous in the preamble) and loading `lmroman10-regular.otf`. Remove it and we have `texgyrepagella-regular.otf`.